# What is the difference between "derivation" and "inference" in logic?

Tags: logic

What is the difference between "derivation" and "inference" in logic?

I see these two words and they confuse me and then there are terms like "derivation rule" and "rule of inference". What are the differences between these terms from a logical perspective?

Comment: Not so a big difference... Usually, *derivation* is used with regard to a formal proof system, while inference is more general (also non deductive).

Comment: "Inference" typically refers to a single step in a derivation, so "derivation" is a sequence of inferences. "Inference rules" are typically the more elementary "derivation rules". But these conventions are not strictly followed.

Comment: I'd concur with Allegranza and Conifold. Derivations are deterministic and extended, whereas inferences are either probabilistic or deterministic and are singular operations. Seems supported by [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/inference).

Comment: A derivation is the result of following specific steps in a particular order. That is step 1, step 2, step 3 and so on until the result is populated.   An interference in deductive reasoning is a relationship between propositions.  That is if I know the truth value of proposition A, THEN I can deduce the value of related propositions to proposition A. For example the contradictory is a relationship to proposition A. Some inference are direct and others are indirect. Many inferences are based on the truth table  which explains the relationship existing.